# ATM assignment - why does balance reflect only most recent transactions?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a ATM that can make deposit, withdrawal and show balance. But I have a problem with the program's balance it only shows the balance for the ten most recent transactions rather than all the transactions made.

I'm not allowed to use global variables,other methods and constants.

Here is how it should work

```
Earlier transactions:
=====================
1 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
=======================
Balance: 55   KR

Earlier transactions:
=====================
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
=======================
Balance: 66   KR
```

Code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bankomat 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Declarer variables
        int[] trans = new int[10];  
        int amount = 0;
        int balance = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        int theChoice = 1;

        while(theChoice != 4)
        {
            theChoice= menu();
            switch(theChoice)
            {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("\nDu valde \"deposit\"");

                    System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                    sum = in.nextInt();

                    if(sum == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nYou have given are wrong value.\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        amount = (int) + sum;
                        makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                    }   

                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("\nDu valde \"withdrawal\"");

                    System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                    sum = in.nextInt();

                    if(sum == 0)
                    {
                        System.out.print("\nDu har angett ett felaktigt belopp.\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        amount = (int) - sum;
                        makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                    }   

                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Balance\"");
                    showTransactions(trans,balance);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Quit\"");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * MENU
     * @return val  skickar tillbaka input värdet
     */
    public static int menu()
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int choice = 0;

        // Den här delen kommer att skriva ut menu
        System.out.println("1. deposit");
        System.out.println("2. withdrawal");
        System.out.println("3. Balance");                   
        System.out.println("4. Quit");                                   
        System.out.print("Your choice: ");

        choice = in.nextInt();

        return choice;
    }

    /**
     *  This method will sum up all the ten latest transaction and show the balance 
     * @param trans   array that saves the latest transactions 
     * @param balance Int that sums up all the values
     */
    public static void showTransactions(int[] trans, int balance )
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tidigare transaktioner: ");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if(trans[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("");
            }

            else
            {
                System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
                balance = balance + trans[i];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");
        System.out.println("Saldo: " + balance + "KR" + "\n" );
    }

    /**
     * This method saves the latest transaction
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @param amount int that saves the latest transaction
     */
    public static void makeTransactions(int[] trans, int amount)
    {
        int position = findNr(trans);
        if(position == -1)
        {
            moveTrans(trans);
            trans[trans.length - 1] = amount;
        }
        else
        {
            trans[position] = amount;
        }
    }

    /**
     * This metod will look for a empty position 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     * @return position 
     */
    private static int findNr(int[] trans) 
    {
        int position = -1;

        for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
        {
            if (trans[i] == 0)
            {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    /**
     * This method will move the transaction 
     * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
     */
    private static void moveTrans(int[] trans)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < (trans.length - 1); i++)
        {
            trans[i] = trans[i + 1];
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: _it only shows the balance for the ten latest transaction_, why do you think it will show some more transaction?

Comment: I think you have translated the comments from another language, right? If so, are you sure they said that the method should "sum up the latest transactions"? Or did they mean "print a summary of the latest transactions, and the balance"? Because I think the balance should not be calculated from the array, otherwise it would not be passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITED] Complete solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Declarer variables
    int[] trans = new int[10];  
    int amount = 0;
    int balance = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int theChoice = 1;

    while(theChoice != 4)
    {
        theChoice= menu();
        switch(theChoice)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"deposit\"");

                System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nYou have given are wrong value.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) + sum;
                    balance += amount;
                    makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"withdrawal\"");

                System.out.print("\nState the value you want to take in: ");
                sum = in.nextInt();

                if(sum == 0)
                {
                    System.out.print("\nDu har angett ett felaktigt belopp.\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    amount = (int) - sum;
                    balance += amount;
                    makeTransactions(trans,amount);
                }   

                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Balance\"");
                showTransactions(trans,balance);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("\nDu valde \"Quit\"");
                break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * MENU
 * @return val  skickar tillbaka input värdet
 */
public static int menu()
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int choice = 0;

    // Den här delen kommer att skriva ut menu
    System.out.println("1. deposit");
    System.out.println("2. withdrawal");
    System.out.println("3. Balance");                   
    System.out.println("4. Quit");                                   
    System.out.print("Your choice: ");

    choice = in.nextInt();

    return choice;
}

/**
 *  This method will sum up all the ten latest transaction and show the balance 
 * @param trans   array that saves the latest transactions 
 * @param balance Int that sums up all the values
 */
public static void showTransactions(int[] trans, int balance )
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Tidigare transaktioner: ");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
    {
        if(trans[i] == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("");
        }

        else
        {
            System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("Saldo: " + balance + "KR" + "\n" );
}

/**
 * This method saves the latest transaction
 * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
 * @param amount int that saves the latest transaction
 */
public static void makeTransactions(int[] trans, int amount)
{
    int position = findNr(trans);
    if(position == -1)
    {
        moveTrans(trans);
        trans[trans.length - 1] = amount;
    }
    else
    {
        trans[position] = amount;
    }
}

/**
 * This metod will look for a empty position 
 * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
 * @return position 
 */
private static int findNr(int[] trans) 
{
    int position = -1;

    for(int i = 0; i < trans.length; i++)
    {
        if (trans[i] == 0)
        {
            position = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    return position;
}

/**
 * This method will move the transaction 
 * @param trans array that saves the latest transactions
 */
private static void moveTrans(int[] trans)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < (trans.length - 1); i++)
    {
        trans[i] = trans[i + 1];
    }   
}
```

Comment: i have to, i can only show the ten lastest transactions

Comment: but you must compute the balance with all! Try with my sample.

Comment: i have to balance in the method showTransactions because for the parameter

Comment: Edited with a complete solution

Answer (score 0):

It only shows the last 10 because you initialze your array to 10 indexes

```
 int[] trans = new int[10];
```

Either make it bigger or use something different.

A great class to use in this case would be a [vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html). You don't need to initialize a size because it resizes itself dynamically.

Now, if you use a vector, but only want to print the last ten transactions, then surround your print statements in conditionals

```
if(i > trans.length - 10)
{
   System.out.print(trans[i] + "\n");
}
```

The reson for this is in your showTransactions() not only are you *printing* the transactions, you are also *adding* them, computing your balance. We want to compute your balance with all your transactions (thus we need to change your array to a vector or other class with dynamic resizing) while also only printing what you need (thus the if statement)

Comment: the program have to show the ten lastest transactions so i can't change that variable

Comment: uhm, yes, you can. If you only want to show the last ten, then add a condition before printing `(if i > trans.length-10){ print...}` and you'll only print what you need (while adding everything)

Comment: inside the for loop ?

Comment: @nillion i added an edit to my answer you should make sure my explanation makes sense.

Comment: it didn't work. the program should work like this   Earlier transactions:
=====================
1 
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
=======================
Balance: 55   KR

Earlier transactions:
=====================
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
=======================
Balance: 66   KR

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because of how you initialized your `int[] trans`. You're only storing the first 10 transactions. You should use `ArrayList` instead, because it's dynamic.

`ArrayList<Integer> trans = new ArrayList<Integer>`, then to add new transactions to your array